# Recursively replace django template tag with sed

Tags: regex, django, bash, sed, find

I renamed something in my django application, and I want to recursively search and replace the tag in all of the templates. I tried to do this using find and sed like so.

```
find . -name *.html -exec sed -i 's/\{\{\s*oldtag\s*\}\}/{{ newtag }}/g' {} \;
```

I get this error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Ok, so I tried a whole bunch of different things to try to make it work. I tried unescaping and double-escaping the curly braces. I tried using [ \t] instead of \s. Nothing seems to work. Some of the combinations don't give an error, but they also don't find or replace anything. What's even worse is sometimes I get this other error.

```
find: paths must precede expression: index.html
```

How can the path precede the expression? . is the path, and it immediately follows the find command. It precedes all the expressions.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify this by using a pipe instead of `-exec`? I'm not a `find` or `sed` expert, but I'd get `sed` working with one file, then use a pipe to pass in the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -i 's|{{\s*oldtag\s*}}|{{ newtag }}|g' {} +
```

With some assumptions:

- your *sed* implementation recognizes the *\s* escape sequence and the *-i* option
- your *find* implementation supports the *{} +* syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping the `'` and `\` characters. This should work:

```
find . -name *.html -exec sed -i \'s/{{\\s*oldtag\\s*}}/{{ newtag }}/g\' {} \;
```

**Tip:** You can always just insert `echo` just before the word `sed` to see a printout of what it looks like (see what is escaped).